# Laravel 6 manipulates the request before being send to validate

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing API endpoints in laravel 6 to support 3rd party to pass a large XML. And I need to manipulate the XML file based on some fields. And I am having trouble figuring out how to modify the request before it is sent to validation.
Is there any existing function that I can use? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class BankStatementsRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Gate::inspect('Broker');
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to create a middleware?

Comment: [Searching shows many suggestions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+laravel+modify+request+before+validation) ... ?